# Windows Store App Incremental Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

So I finally got my listview content to serialize and write to a file so I can restore my apps state across different sessions.  Now I'm wondering if there is a way I can incrementally serialize and save my data.  Currently, I call this method in the SaveState method of my mainpage:

```
    private async void writeToFile()
    {
        var f = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("data.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (var st = await f.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            var s = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Item>),
                                   new Type[] { typeof(Item) });
            s.WriteObject(st, convoStrings);
        }
    }
```

What I think would be more ideal is to write out data to storage as it is generated, so I don't have to serialize my entire list in the small suspend time frame, but I don't know if this is possible to incrementally serialize my collection, and if it is, how would I do it?

Note that my data doesn't change after it is generated, so I don't have to worry about anything other than appending new data to the end of my currently serialized list.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you definition when to save the data to the hard drive. Maybe you want to save the new collection state when a new collection item is added or removed? Or when the content of an item changes.

The main problem about saving everything just in time to the hard drive  is, that is  may be doggy slow. If you're using an `async` programming model, it wouldn't be a problem directly since your app won't hang since yeah, everything is async.

I think it may be a  better idea to save the collection say every minute AND when the user closes the application. This will only work if you're dealing with a cerain amount of data  since you only have about 3 seconds to perform all the IO stuff.

As you can see, there is no perfect solution. It really depends on your requirements and the size of the data. Without further information thats all I can tell you for sure.

Comment: I'm currently saving my data when the app is closed, but I agree that a better way to do this would be to save it as the collection is modified, but I'm not sure how to incrementally save this information using serialization.  I don't want to re-write the whole collection every time I save because old data doesn't change, the collection is only ever added to and no other modifications made.  So I want to be able to "append" to my current serialized data.

Comment: Appending data is easy but what if data "in the middle" of the file is changed? You would have to read the whole file, find the location where the changed data is locates and overwrite just that bytes. And if your previous data was less then the new one? You would have to rewrite all the bytes that came after etc. I am not sure if there's anything built in to do that ...

Comment: My data doesn't change, only new data is added.  So when new data is added, I want to take my serialized string and update it to include this new data...